# HTTPError when sending POST with urllib2 with params

Tags: python, django, post, urllib2, urllib

I am trying to send a POST request with some parameters using this code:

```
def _ws_save_manifest(self):
    url = 'http://localhost:8000/extras/save_manifest/'

    xml_string = 'example'
    params = {'xml_string': xml_string}
    data = urllib.urlencode(params)
    request = urllib2.Request(url, data)
    request.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5')
    request.add_header('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

    #response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    result = json.load(response)
    if result['ok']:
        return True
    return False
```

However I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 528, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: FORBIDDEN
```

Using GET, i have no problems at all, but when sending headers, problems come up.

By the way: the request is using django and that's the url (which works perfectly with GET):

```
url(r'^extras/save_manifest/$', 'extras.views.save_manifest'),
```

Comment: AFAICS this is a server problem

Comment: wong2 just updated the question/post

Comment: More server side codes?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that POST requests with django are Cross Site Request Forgery protected.
Look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/ for more information.